# Understanding the signature of <$>

Tags: haskell, ghci, applicative

I have the applicative `<$>` operator more or less figured out, but I can't understand the signature I'm getting with the following example:

```
ghci>  let f x y z = x + y + z  -- f::Num a => a -> a -> a -> a
ghci> f <$> Just 2 <*> Just 3 <*> Just 4 
Just 9
```

This result I understand, but when checking the following type:

```
ghci> :t (<$> f)
(<$> f) :: Num a => ((a -> a -> a) -> b) -> a -> b  --This makes no sense to me
```

That signature I would understand as : a function that takes a `(a -> a- > a) -> b` function and an `a` as parameters and returns a `b`. According to this reasoning , I should call this like :

```
 (<$>f) f 4
```

which would result in an `Integer`. 
 Obviously this is not true, so can you please help me understand how to read the type of `(<$> f)`?

Comment: Are you sure you're not interested in the type of `(f <$>)` instead? Note that `(f <$>)` is the same as `(<$>) f`, i.e., the partial application of `(<$>)` to its first argument, but `(<$> f)` is the partial application of `(<$>)` to its *second* argument.

Comment: The `<$>` operator is just an alias for `fmap` from the `Functor` typeclass.  I agree with @kosmikus that you may have meant to try `:t (f <$>)` or possibly `:t (<$>) f` (these are equivalent) instead.

Comment: You're both absolutely right, what I was looking for was `(f <$>)` !!! But now I'm left wondering, why does my reasoning not hold when talking about `(<$> f)`, how to read its signature ?

Comment: @Chirlo there is a `functor` instance for functions, too. This is why you're getting the weird signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a function that takes a `(a -> a- > a) -> b` function and an `a` as parameters and returns a `b`.

This is correct.

> According to this reasoning , I should call this like :
>
> ```
> (<$>f) f 4
> ```
>
> which would result in an `Integer`.

No, because `f` does not have type `(a -> a -> a) -> b` or one compatible with it. Instead it has type `Num a => a -> a -> a -> a`. That is, `f` takes three numbers and produces a number, whereas we're looking for a function that takes a function (of type `a -> a -> a`) as its first argument.

Comment: I see, I failed to realize that `(a -> a -> a)` is a function itself! So for example `(<$> f ) (\g -> g 2 3) 4` satisfies the signature. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`<$>` takes as a second argument something of type `g b`, where `g` is any applicative functor.

You are passing `f :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> a` as a second argument. Let's ignore the `Num a` context to keep things simple.

Hence, we look for `g,b` such that `g b = a -> a -> a -> a`.

Let's write the type of `f` in prefix form:

```
f :: (->) a ((->) a ((->) a a)) = g b
```

Hence, `g = (->) a` and `b = ((->) a ((->) a a))`. The latter is `b = a -> a -> a` in infix form.

It happens that `(->) a` is an applicative functor, so `<$> f` type checks. Note however that `<$>` is used on a completely different functor than the `Maybe` one you were using in your examples. Hence the confusion.

TL;DR: overloaded identifiers can shapeshift to many things adapting to their contexts, possibly in some unexpected way.